# Prevent RABL (with Rails) auto-singularizing aliases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I'm attempting to make JSON that looks something like this:

```
elements: {
    nodes: [
      { data: { id: 'j', title: 'Jerry' } },
      { data: { id: 'e', title: 'Elaine' } },
      { data: { id: 'k', title: 'Kramer' } },
      { data: { id: 'g', title: 'George' } }
    ],
    edges: [
      { data: { source: 'j', target: 'e' } },
      { data: { source: 'j', target: 'k' } },
      { data: { source: 'k', target: 'j' } },
   ]
}
```

With [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl). My code looks like this:

```
object @work => :elements

child :nodes, :root => :nodes, :object_root => "data".pluralize do
    attributes :id, :title
end

child :links, :root => :edges, :object_root => :data do
    attribute :parent_id => :source
    attribute :child_id => :target
end
```

But my JSON still reads

```
{"elements":
    {"nodes":[
        {"datum":{"id":j,"title":"Jerry"}},
        {"datum":{"id":k,"title":"Kramer"}},
```

etc...

As you can see, I've tried the `.pluralize` function, even `.pluralize(2)` to try to force it to recognize it as multiple, but to no avail. It seems like RABL is probably calling `.singularize` somewhere down the line, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

I need it to read "data" instead of "datum" because of a library I'm using ([cytoscape.js](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/)), which requires the JSON to be formatted a specific way. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Basically, appending an s to the plural version of the word will singularize it to back to the plural version, not the singular version.

It's a bit cheesy, but this code in `show.json.rabl`:

```
object @work => :elements

child :nodes, :root => :nodes, :object_root => :datas do
    attributes :id, :title
end

child :links, :root => :edges, :object_root => :datas do
    attribute :parent_id => :source
    attribute :child_id => :target
end
```

yields

```
"elements":{
    "nodes":[
         {"data":{"id":820,"title":"Jerry"}},
         {"data":{"id":821,"title":"Elaine"}}
```

etc.

I believe it's because the singularize function doesn't recognize "datas" since it's not a word, so it drops the s by default. Someone who knows ruby a bit better than I might be able to corroborate/shoot that down.

This is probably pretty obvious to people, but perhaps it will help someone like myself who hadn't thought of it.